# Verificar se elemento existe dentro de outro elemento com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de eu verificar se uma estrutura existe dentro de outra com Javascript?

Por exemplo: verificar se a `div` "filho" esta dentro da "pai" para executar uma função:

```
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe, basta você tentar selecionar o elemento no DOM e verificar sua existência. Tratando-se de elementos com o atributo `id` definido, basta fazer:

```js
const pai = document.getElementById("pai");
const filho = pai.querySelector("#filho");

if (filho !== null) {
  console.log("O elemento #filho existe em #pai");
} else {
  console.log("O elemento #filho não existe em #pai");
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho"></div>
</div>
```

Perceba o elemento filho foi buscado com referência ao objeto `pai`. Isso significa que a busca será feita apenas na árvore de DOM definida pelo elemento pai, e não todo o documento.

Veja funcionando em uma situação que o elemento filho não existe:

```js
const pai = document.getElementById("pai");
const filho = pai.querySelector("#filho");

if (filho !== null) {
  console.log("O elemento #filho existe em #pai");
} else {
  console.log("O elemento #filho não existe em #pai");
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Ótimo, isso mesmo, bem explicado.

Answer (score 2):

Em `querySelector` é possível usar os selectores CSS, então é possível usar [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) - `pai > filho`.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#pai > #filho");

if (elem) {
  console.log("Elemento encontrado");
} else {
  console.log("Elemento nao encontrado");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
s
```

```html
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opá, melhor ainda!

Comment: Bem lembrado. +1

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a busca no dom através da div pai, por exemplo:

`js
pai = document.querySelector('.pai'):
possui_div_filho = pai.querySelector('.filho') != null;`

Answer (score -3):

Acho que da pra fazer assim também

> Se existir a tag(filho) ele retorná True, se não ele retorna False;

```
let filho = document.getElementById('filho');
let existencia = document.body.contains(filho);

if(existencia == True){
     function desejada();
}
```

Da uma olhada nesse site aqui

https://horadecodar.com.br/2022/01/04/como-verificar-se-elemento-existe-no-dom-com-javascript/

Comment: Não precisa de contains, se o elemento não existir o getElementById já vai retornar null, usar o contains dessa forma é redundante. O que o AP quer é verificar dentro de outro elemento especifico.

Comment: Pensei que ele queria saber se um determinado item expecifico esta no codigo, mas reli e entendi que ele quer saber se um determinado item esta dentro de outro. Sorry